Issue with Node.js Version and node-sass in Stencil CLI in Bigcommerce
I am currently using Node.js version 18 and have encountered an issue when attempting to run Stencil CLI with a lower version of Node.js. When using versions below 18, I receive an error indicating that Stencil is not supported. However, Node.js 18 works fine but I am experiencing issues with SCSS not being included in the design when running locally.
I am getting the following error:
This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (/home/sagmetic/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sagmetic/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:13:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:10)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
    at ScssCompiler.activateNodeSassEngine (/home/sagmetic/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-styles/lib/ScssCompiler.js:21:23)
    at StencilStyles.activateEngine (/home/sagmetic/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-styles/lib/styles.js:52:36)


What I have tried:

Running npm rebuild node-sass as suggested in the error message.
Ensuring that my environment and dependencies are correctly set up.

Environment:

Node.js version: 18.20.3
Stencil CLI

Questions:

How can I resolve the issue with SCSS not being included in the design?
Is there a specific compatibility issue between Node.js 18 and node-sass that I should be aware of?
Are there additional steps I should take to ensure Stencil CLI works correctly with Node.js 18?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Stencil does not work on node 18.20. I have found that node 18.15 works well.

I tried with node 18.15 , but I am still getting the same issue
